# SKVectorMapView: unrecognized selector

Tags: skmaps

I'm implementing Skobbler SDK (v2.5) but I've an issue with firsts steps.

App crashes with this error:
[SKVectorMapView displayTrafficWithMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

This is the code of AppDelegate

```
SKMapsInitSettings* initSettings = [[SKMapsInitSettings alloc]init];
initSettings.mapDetailLevel = SKMapDetailLevelLight;

[[SKMapsService sharedInstance] initializeSKMapsWithAPIKey:API_KEY settings:initSettings];
```

And this is the ViewController's code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     SKMapView *mapView = [[SKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f,  CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) )];
     [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```

Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: The traffic API is not available by default in the SDK (you need a traffic enabled build) - do you have one such build or are you using the public SDK?

Comment: I've the SDK downloaded from [link](developer.skobbler.com) and a Mobile API key generated by Skobbler.com. No traffic API I need

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you added "-ObjC" to your "other linker flag".

"Select the project and choose your target. Choose the Build settings tab and in the Other linker flags option introduce -ObjC."
from developer.skobbler.com

Comment: My fault, I didn't realize that I've added -Objc not -ObjC. Now it works